# Hypersurface on $\mathbb{P}^m\times\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I have found a statement (Harris "Algebraic Geometry", p.269) saying  that a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^m\times\mathbb{P}^n$ can be written as a single equation. I couldn't find the proof.

> How can I prove it? Is there a good reference for the statement?

Comment: The equation is just given by a bi-homogeneous polynomial of bi-degree $(m, \, n)$.

Comment: This site is for questions of math research, please consider using [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand my comment into a short answer. A subset $X \subset \mathbb{P}^m \times \mathbb{P}^n$ is a closed algebraic subvariety if and only if it is given by a system of polynomial equations $$G_k(x_0, \ldots, x_m; \, y_0, \ldots, y_n)=0 \quad \operatorname{for}\;k=1, \ldots, t,$$ homogeneous separately in each set of variables $x_i$ and $y_j$. In particular, if $X$ is a hypersurface one has $t=1$, for dimension reasons. See for instance [**1**, Theorem 1 p. 57].

**References.**

**[1]** I. G. Shafarevich: *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*, Second Edition, Springer 1994.